# DOMPDF generating blank pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF library 0.6.0 beta 3 to generate pdf files using PHP. Some of my html can be processed to PDF correctly and some not. Below is an example of one which can not. I have validated my html via w3c html validator. What can I do to resolve this issue?

```
<?php
  require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
              <title></title>
                      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
              </head>
             <body>
                 <p>Algarve Bird Watching Festival About to Begin</p>
                 <p><span style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>&nbsp;</span></p>
                 <p>Test Title</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet<sup>th</sup> Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet </p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet </p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet <a href='http://www.test.com'>test</a>
                  Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet &nbsp; 
                  </p>
    <p><span style='font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt'>&nbsp;</span></p>
             </body>
             </html>";

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
?>
```

Comment: You should remove some line after line and always check, if DOMPDF will work without that line.

Comment: A blank PDF or a completely blank page? Do you get any errors from PHP?

Comment: @ersel Hey Ersel, how did you solved this issue? I am facing this exact problem and am getting nowhere with it. Can you help me by explaining what you did?

Comment: Hi Sushil, I ended up switching to another library. I can't remember which one I used though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your double quotes:

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
          <title></title>
                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
          </head>
         <body>
             <p>Algarve Bird Watching Festival About to Begin</p>
             <p><span style="font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
             <p>Test Title</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet<sup>th</sup> Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet </p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet</p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet </p>
             <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>
              Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet &nbsp; 
              </p>
<p><span style="font-family:calibri;font-size:11pt">&nbsp;</span></p>
         </body>
         </html>';
```

---

### edit

furthermore, DOMPDF may not know the font calibri.

---

### edit

You don't have a `<title>` tag content. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, I have miscopied my code updated now, I have installed calibri font into DOMPDF. Some of my html files gets output fine with calibri.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass single quotes in html strings passed to DOM PDF.

Your html string needs to have double quotes.

If you use tables, then do not use thead or tbody.

That's another issue I ran into.

Basically if DOM PDF thinks a string of html is broken, it craps out without a warning.